# Not able to read large CSV file on google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gcloud

I have a google cloud VM instance. I am trying to upload and read CSV of 5.5 mb, but the google cloud server can't read it. So I tried uploading smaller file and it read successfully. So how can I read huge CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue reading your 5.5MB file, but as alternative you can try to put it in a bucket and try to read it from gsutil.

In the meanwhile, if you could provide more details on how you are trying to read it CSV could be helpful trying to help you with the issue.